# Como se resuelve el problema de los filosofos comensales usando QSemaphore

Tags: c++, qt

Por mas que busco solo encuentro como hacerlo usando la libreria  pero necesito hacerlo con  y la verdad no entiendo mucho de esto y c++ no es mi fuerte por no decir que no lo entiendo masomenos nos dijeron en donde debiamos hacer la sincronizacion pero por mas que lo intento no me sirve. Estoy usando QTCreator, es la primera vez que lo utilizo.

Esta es mi clase hilofilosofo.h

```
    #ifndef HILOFILOSOFO_H
    #define HILOFILOSOFO_H
    #include <QObject>
    #include <QThread>
    #include <QSemaphore>
    #define N 5 //número de filosofos
    #define IZQ (i+N-1)%N //macro con el número del vecino izq de i
    #define DER (i+1)%N //macro con el número del vecino der de i
    #define PENSANDO 0 //filosofo pensando
    #define HAMBRIENTO 1 //el filósofo trata de obtener los tenedores
    #define COMIENDO 2 //filosofo comiendo
    class HiloFilosofo : public QThread
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit HiloFilosofo(QObject *parent = nullptr);
        HiloFilosofo(QSemaphore *semaforo, int i, unsigned int tiempo);
    signals:
    protected:
            void run(); //metodo a sobreescribir
    public slots: //eventos o metodos
        void pensar(int i); //el filósofo esta pensando
        void tomarTenedores(int i); // adquiere dos tenedores o se bloquea
        void comer(int i); //come spagueti
        void ponerTenedores(int i); //pone de vuelta ambos tenedores en la mesa
        void probar(int i);
    private:
        int i; //representa el número de filosofo
        int milisegundos;
        QSemaphore *semaforo; //variable de cerrojo
        int estado[N]; //HAMBRIENTO, PENSANDO, COMIENDO
    };
    #endif // HILOFILOSOFO_H
```

Esta es mi clase hilofilosofo.cpp

```
    #include <stdio.h> //printf
    #include "hilofilosofo.h"
    HiloFilosofo::HiloFilosofo(QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)    {    }
    HiloFilosofo::HiloFilosofo(QSemaphore *semaforo, int i, unsigned int tiempo) : QThread(nullptr)
    {
        this->semaforo = semaforo;
        this->i = i;
        this->milisegundos = tiempo;
        this->estado[i] = HAMBRIENTO; //estado inicial del filosofo
    }
    void HiloFilosofo::run(){
        forever{
            pensar(i);//esta pensando
            tomarTenedores(i);//trata de tomar dos tenedores
            comer(i);//esta comiendo
            ponerTenedores(i);//libera los tenedores
            msleep(milisegundos);
        }
    }
    void HiloFilosofo::pensar(int i){
        printf("Filosofo %d pensando9\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
    void HiloFilosofo::comer(int i){
        printf("Filosofo %d comiendo9\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
    void HiloFilosofo::tomarTenedores(int i){
        estado[i] = HAMBRIENTO; //registra el estado actual
        //AQUI SE DEBE SINCRONIZAR CON SEMAFOROS
        probar(i); //trata de adquirir los dos tenedores
    }

    void HiloFilosofo::ponerTenedores(int i){
        estado[i] = PENSANDO; //e filosofo termino de comer
        //AQUI SE DEBE SINCRONIZAR CON SEMAFOROS
        probar(IZQ); //verifica si el vecino izquierdo puede comer ahora
        probar(DER); //verifica si el vecino derecho puede comer ahora
    }
    void HiloFilosofo::probar(int i){
        if(estado[i]==HAMBRIENTO&&estado[IZQ]!=COMIENDO&&estado[DER]!=COMIENDO){
            //AQUI SE DEBE SINCRONIZAR CON SEMAFOROS
            estado[i] = COMIENDO;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Has probado el QMutex? quizás pueda ayudarte

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html

Comment: no puedo usar QMutex, es obligatorio usar QSemaphore